# CakePHP virtual field: replace one string with another

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I wonder if there is any way to declare a virtual field in CakePHP to do the following:
We have to replace a user's status with a symbol and append to it the user's nickname. For example, if a user is an admin, we want to display: `@barth`, for a regular user `~barth`.

I already wrote an `afterFind()` callback to perform this task, but it fails using the `containable` behavior.

Either is there another way to implement it, or we can create a virtual field. The latter solution would be very elegant, but after googling I cannot find any way to use MySQL syntax to replace one string with another.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) are very easy to use in Cake. You can use any regular MySQL function in their declaration to achieve this type of thing.

You'll first need to determine the SQL command to achieve what you want, I'd suggest using the `CONCAT()` function:

```
-- Return an @ concatenated onto the username
CONCAT('@', yourfield)
```

Then add this as a virtual field in your model:

```
class YourModel extends AppModel {
    public $virtualFields = array(
        'yourVirtualField' => 'CONCAT("@", yourfield)'
    );
}
```

Now, when you query this model you should be able to access it like this:

```
$example = $this->YourModel->find('first');
echo $example['YourModel']['yourVirtualField']; // @yourfield
```

---

## Edit

Since your update, you've got the values you want to concatenate together in another model as virtual fields already. [CakePHP doesn't allow you to use associated models' virtual fields when creating a new virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields), but you can do a subselect query to manually get this data. [Here's an SQL Fiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6b8a5/5)

Comment: Looks very good. But what still is missing: the distinction. How to define more symbols? For example '@' for `administrator`, '~' for `regular`, etc. to perform it in just one request?

Comment: You'll possibly need to do this with SQL - can you provide an example of how you'd determine which level the user is? You could use an IF or CASE statement to decide which symbol to prepend

Comment: I never used IF or CASE in MySQL so it would be nice to have an example on that. How I will use it? I will for example `contain` user data to another models and want to get only two fields: `username` and `symbol`. Therefore `symbol` needs to be a virtual field, which needs to be defined to return a symbol depending on the value of `status` column.

Comment: Hi Barth, please provide a specific example of this. As per the manual, [associated models cannot be used within virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields) from a model, but you'd still be able to get this the old fashioned way with an SQL subselect.

Comment: If the correct symbol for the user is stored alongside the username, you could just do `CONCAT(symbol, username)` in the model that it belongs to as a virtual field.

Comment: `class User { $this->virtualFields = ['symbol' => 'some tricky SQL to return a value depending on what is in another column in the users table']; }`. I'd rather not store this symbol because of redundancy and implementation difficulties in this specific case. I guess I will have to do it some another way, for example an angular filter in the frontend to translate the status to symbol...

Comment: OK, can you use the tricky SQL in the new virtual field as well? Here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6b8a5/5) with an example of how you could return a prefixed username with subselects

Comment: Thank you. It works. I really appreciate your help. If you please post a link to this fiddle in your answer, I will be glad to mark it as accepted.